# Return average / mean of a specific key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, iteration

**This is probably a duplicate, so please let me know if I didn't find something.**

My question is in the title.

I know that the following code would do it, but I don't think this is how it should be done. Can this be compacted to a cleaner function that does the same thing? What about a builtin function?

```
def find_sorted_avg(dict_list, key):
    total = 0

    for item in dict_list:
        total += item[key]

    return total / len(dict_list)
```

Please let me know if you know of a better way of doing that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `dict_list`, and what you'd expect the output to be? If this code is working, you may want to check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: should be better: `total = sum(item[key] for item in dict_list) / len(dict_list)`

Comment: Do you mean `total += item[key]`

Comment: @jacoblaw probably! edited (else it doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That was a typo. I accepted your answer, it seems like the most "pythonic" way to complete this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want to sum all values of a `key` in your list of dicts.

You can feed a generator comprehension to `sum`, and divide by the length of the list, in one line:

```
total = sum(item.get(key,0) for item in dict_list) / len(dict_list)
```

`get(key,0)` ensures that if the key is absent from one dict, it will still work (0 is issued when key isn't in the dictionary)

(of course if you want this to crash loudly instead replace `item.get(key,0)` by `item[key]`)

Comment: ok, that's already more than OP asks. I have edited my post ('accounted for' is probably bad wording)